# Google Docs Equation help (countif with multiple criteria and or)

Tags: web-applications, google-sheets

I'm struggling with a fairly simple equation in Google Docs.

I need to check column A is a specific name.
I need to check column B is a number or a specific string.

Written out it would read like this:

Count if column A equals "rich" and column B is a number or equals "test"

Comment: Unless this is a Google Apps Script problem (in which case post your code) this question is better suited to [webapps.se]

Comment: The filter method below was just what I needed (it ended up looking like)    
`=counta(iferror(filter(A:A;A:A=A4;isNumber(B:B));""))`  
  
I also needed to count the values of a certain cell if the same criteria was met, that looks like:    
`=sum(iferror(filter(B:B;A:A=A4;isNumber(B:B))),0)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use a formula like this:

```
=counta(iferror(filter(A:A;A:A=C9;B:B=E9);""))+counta(iferror(filter(A:A;A:A=C9;B:B=D9);""))
```

where your conditions are written in cell C9, D9, E9.
C9 for the condition of column A and D9, E9 the conditions for Column B